# How to fix PHP curl error CURLE_SSH (79) when using sftp to upload file

Tags: php, curl, ssh, sftp, libssh2

I'm trying to reproduce the following command to upload a file via sftp on my PHP app:

```
curl -T /var/repo/file -u user:password sftp://server.com/folder/
```

The above commands works just fine (I had to recompile libcurl on my ubuntu box in order to make it work, though). However, when I tried to use PHP's curl library, things didn't go so well for me.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$localfile = 'file';
$fp = fopen($localfile, 'r');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'sftp://server.com/folder/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:password');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($localfile));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_exec ($ch);
$error_no = curl_errno($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

if ($error_no == 0) {
    $error = 'File uploaded succesfully.';
} else {
    $error = 'File upload error.';
}
echo $error.' '.$error_no;
```

This gives back error 79: CURLE_SSH (79) which I dont know how to fix. Have you faced this problem? How did you fix it? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What curl version and what libssh2 version are you using on what operating system? Which PHP version are you using and which version of the PHP curl extension?

Comment: curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8k zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.15 libssh2/1.2.2
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz

Comment: Over ubuntu 11.10 with PHP 5 .. ill get back to you on the curl extension version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means libcurl got some kind of error from the "SSH layer" (libssh2). If you enable VERBOSE you might see further details.

You're using fairly old libcurl and libssh2 versions so it is not unthinkable that you can fix this problem simply by upgrading those to modern versions.

Comment: I'll do just that and see where it gets me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This question was asked long ago and I no longer have access to the environment in question "/ adding -vvv to connections helped.